# Error when calling posts.content

Tags: class, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting this error

> undefined method`content'for"Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000104e87060"

When I do `<%= @user.posts.content %>`

but when I do `<%= @user.posts.count %>` everything shows up normal and it works... I don't understand why I can call count and it show's the number of posts in the users show.html.erb page but when I try and show the content it throws and error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You also had a typo in the question when you said `but when I do <%= @user.posts.content %> everything shows up normal and it works` actually you wanted to say `but when I do <%= @user.posts.count %> everything shows up normal and it works`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<%= @user.posts.content %>`

**Use this**

```
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>   
  <%= post.content %>
<% end %>
```

`@user.posts` return a collection of posts. So, when you call count you get the count of all records returned by @user.posts. BUT in order to access `content` attribute of each `post`, you will need to iterate over the collection and display the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks Kirti! I actually figured it out before you answered lol! Why do you have to iterate through instead of just using @user.posts.content? Is there a good read for this? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Glad to help:). Read the notes in my answer. Using `@user.posts.content` will give you error as you try to access an attribute on an array.